# React Native: Network Request Failed, but didn't actually

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch

I have this simple network request:

```
registerDevice(data) {
    return new Promise((next, error) => {
      fetch(SERVER_URL + '/devices', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
      })
      .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
          next(responseData);
      })
      .catch((err) => error(err));
    })
  }
```

Every time it gets executed, I'm getting a

```
Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror...
```

although there is **no error**, the data is successfully POSTed and I'm getting correct response headers.

RN is 0.33 and I'm compiling for Android. Errors on Android versions 4.4.4, 5.0.1, 6.0.1 and 7.0

Comment: Where is `XMLHttpRequest` used?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Which portion of linked documentation are you referencing?

Comment: It's just a regular fetch() request in React, it's using XMLHttpRequest actually.

Comment: _"it's using XMLHttpRequest actually"_ What do you mean?

Comment: The question is tagged with "react-native" and fetch. Your questions seem like you don't really understand what my question is about, so - nothing, thank you, and sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Are you stating that the `fetch()` call is converted into an `XMLHttpRequest()` call? See also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222#issuecomment-170239302

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 syntax. Your code will look like this:

```
fetch(url,{method:'POST',body:data})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => console.log("Booo"));
```

Ref: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/

== Edit ==

Sorry, maybe you can try using `await` and `async`. Code:

```
let response = await fetch(this.api_url,{
    method:'POST',
    body: data
})

let responseJson = await response.json();
return responseJson;
```

Could you explain more on the error you are receiving?

Comment: Please take another look to what I've written and tell me if it's not ES6 syntax.

Comment: I try on android and it works well, can you expand your error output?